# Is S is an open set?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $ S =\{z: z=2 \} \cup \{z : |z| < 2\}$ an open set?

My attempt:  Here I take  $A = \{z: z=2\}$ to be closed and $B = \{ z : |z| < 2\} $ to be open, that is  $ A  \cup B$ = closed + open = open.

Is this true?

Any hints/solution?

Comment: Why do you think closed union open is open?

Comment: It is not true that "open + closed = open". But I have a question. is $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ or $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: @Calvin  khor i take even  as  closed  and odd as open  now   even + odd = odd....i may be  wrong i just used this logics

Comment: I wouldnt do that^.

Comment: Ok, well it doesn't work that way unfortunately. The 1D version is perhaps easier to understand : $(-2,2)\cup \{2\}=(-2,2]$ is not open.

Comment: @CalvinKhor   good....now i  understand  thanks u

Comment: You're welcome, glad you understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not open since any neighbourhood of $z = 2$ contains $z = 2+\epsilon \notin S$ for a sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: False in discrete topology.

Comment: @Zeekless You're right, but under such topology, every set is clopen, so there's nothing to ask.

Comment: @Zeekless why is the discrete topology relavant when the OP has already used a norm in the question, and the question is tagged under `complex-analysis`?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Great point!

Comment: @CalvinKhor, not a norm, but an absolute value of a (complex) number, which may or may not work as a norm which produces topology. I totally understand the irrelevance.